# Cross platform development when using GDAL

Tags: gdal

We want to use GDAL in our Java application and the application will deployed in different environment like Win/Linux/Docker. Out development env based on Win 10.

Since the GDAL java binding depends on the native library, and the native library is platform dependent.

So the packaged application will not work in another environment.

How do you solve that?